# How do i add master generated files to all branches

Tags: git, branch, git-branch

While working on sub-branches from the master, I checked the absence of the .gitignore file and created the .gitignore file on the master.
Now how do you add .gitignore to the remaining branches?

```
1. master -> foo -> first
             ㄴ---> second
2. master add .gitignore file
3. I want foo, first, second branchs add .gitignore file
```

Comment: By checkout out each branch and either merging master or cherry-picking that revision where you added `.gitignore`.

Comment: It was a little troublesome, but I checked out with each branch and merged it with the master. Thank you so much!

Comment: If it's 50 branches, you could try with a bash 1-liner. Some things get out of the scope of git to solve it. `git branch | grep -v master | while read branch; do git checkout $branch; git merge master; done` _or_ something like that.

Comment: Don't include the solution in the question. Post as a separate answer.

Comment: solution:
`(master) $ git switch foo`
`(foo)    $ git merge master`
`(foo)    $ git switch first`
`(first)  $ git merge master`
`(first)  $ git switch second`
`(second) $ git merge master`
After checking out each branch, the master was merged.
Thank you guys!

Comment: I would probably downvote said answer. For example, you may not want to merge the entire branch into each other branch just to get one file. You probably want to use `git cherry-pick` instead.

Comment: I'm studying git cherry-pick! I'm just starting to learn how to git. Thank you for letting me know!